# Calling async function multiple times in short time messes up shopping cart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, promise

I build a shopping cart for my online shop.
When an item is not in the cart yet, I add it. Else, I increase the quantity.
This works well when the add item button is not clicked too often in a row.
If I have like 20 products in my cart and I increase the quantity fast (e.g. click fast), I'll get duplicates of the products in my shopping cart and order list.

I think I got a bug in my code, maybe someone sees my mistake.
Has this to do with the async function?

Note: In this setup I got to make an API-call every time an item gets added. This can't be changed at this point.

```
async addProduct({ commit, state, dispatch, getters }, item) {
  try {
    if (getters.gotThisItemAlready(item)) {
      console.error("ITEM ALREADY HERE");
      dispatch("changeItemQuantity", { item, quantity: 1 });
      return;
    }

    let { order } = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));

    item.quantity = 1;

    if (!order.items.length) {
      order = await API.createOrder([item]);
    } else {
      order.items.push(item);
      order = await API.updateExistingOrder(order);
    }

    order.items.forEach((item: any, index: number) => {
      const article = articles.find(
        (a: any) => a.articleID === item.articleID
      );
      if (article) {
        Vue.set(order.items, index, Object.assign({}, article, item));
      }
    });
    commit("updateOrder", order);
  } catch ({ message }) {
    console.error(message);
  }
},

async changeItemQuantity({ commit, state }, { item, quantity = 1 }: any) {
  try {

    let { order} = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));

    order.items.forEach((i: any, index: number) => {
      if (i.articleID === item.articleID) {
        if (
          i.quantity + quantity > -1 &&
          i.quantity + quantity <= item.stock[0].stock
        ) {
          i.quantity += quantity;
        }
        if (i.quantity === 0) {
          order.items.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
    });

    order = await API.updateExistingOrder(order);

    order.items.forEach((item: any, index: number) => {
      const article = articles.find(
        (a: any) => a.articleID === item.articleID
      );
      if (article) {
        Vue.set(order.items, index, Object.assign({}, article, item));
      }
    });
    commit("updateOrder", order);
  } catch ({ message }) {
    console.error(message);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the intended behaviour if someone clicks the button twice fast?

Comment: The quantity should go up by 1 on every click if article is already in the cart. Else it should be added to the shoppiing cart

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to add an item multiple times, so your function should not queue up calls. You need to ignore inputs while you're processing in addItem().

```js
let busy = false;
async function takesAWhile() {
    if (busy) {
        console.log('busy. ignoring you');
        return;
    }
    // do some stuff
    busy = true;
    console.log('starting hard stuff');
    await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        setTimeout(resolve,1000);
    })
    console.log('done');
    busy = false;
}

takesAWhile();
takesAWhile();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue many times in the past. A simple solution is just to disable the button right after it's clicked and then enable it again once your API call is complete. If the call takes a long time, you can consider using a disable with a spinner.

```html
<button :disabled="isDisabled" @click="addItem">add item</button>
```

Then in your handler you can do something like:

```js
this.isDisabled = true;
await doExpensiveAPICall();
this.isDisabled = false;
```

Make sure your `button[disabled]` CSS does something reasonable to make your buttons look disabled.

Comment: Also, need some error handling if `doExpensiveAPICalls()` rejects or the button gets stuck in the disabled state.

Comment: Yeah, in that case what I like to do is enable the button again and show the user some kind of feedback in the UI.